# How can I share a WQHD monitor & Apple bluetooth keyboard/mouse between a Mac and PC?

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, keyboard, bluetooth

I have a Mac Mini that is connect to a 30" WQHD (2560 x 1600) Dual-DVI monitor and Apple bluetooth keyboard and magic trackpad.

I'm building a Windows 7 PC and I'd like to have my work space setup in a way that allows me to share the monitor, keyboard, and trackpad between the two computers so all I have to do is push a button on some KVM-like device that allows me to switch back and forth.  My questions are...

1. Since the monitor is a Dual-DVI display and the keyboard/trackpad are bluetooth devices, do I even need a KVM switch?
2. If not, is there a monitor-only switch I can use that supports a dual-dvi display?
3. For my PC, do I need to install a bluetooth receiver to use the Apple keyboard/trackpad? I don't think the motherboard has bluetooth built in.
4. Since the key layout on the Apple keyboard is different than a PC keyboard, what's a good way to manage the differences between the two platforms? Some kind of keyboard mapping tool?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

***UPDATE:***
For the Keyboard & Trackpad, it looks like the Synergy software is the best solution. I still don't know how to share the monitor, however.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give this a try: http://www.share-mouse.com/teleport-windows.htm

There are various other apps much like this one around the web that can do this trick. It's an easy software solution.

Comment: Please see http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers to learn about how to properly recommend a piece of software to another user. Additionally, it would be appreciated if you took the time to correct spelling mistakes in your posts before you submit it to the site :)